# Sprint boot jar as dependent jar of other boot application

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, dependencies

My project struture is like this

```
Project 1(Spring boot)  
    dependencies   

       project 2(spring boot jar)  
       project 3(normal jar)
```

When i execute maven clean install for project 1. It gives compilation error such that Project 2(boot jar), dependent Project's class not found,though project 3's classes do create any problem. When I open project 2's jar, classes are inside BOOT-INF folder,How to resolve this problem?can I somehow let MAVEN know that project 2 is boot jar,search class inside BOOT-INF.

Comment: When you run maven install, each project is compiled by itself. If project 2 depends on project 3, it must be declared in project 2 pom file.

Answer (score 0):

As already commented, project 2 needs a dependency on project 3, to use its classes/resources.

Anyway, having a dependency to a spring boot application (project 1 to project 2) is something to avoid.

Instead split up project 2 into 2 aretefacts :

1. project-2-app
2. project-2-jar

and let

- project-2-app depend on project-2-jar
- project-1 depend on project-2-jar only, not on project-2-app

Comment: Why is it "something to avoid" ?